# How to add reviews to the book

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I've two content-types "Book" & "Review". I want users of role `reviewers` to add reviews to any book they desire.

**How I did it?:**

I've added entity-reference to Book from Review with (auto-complete) widget. This just allows reviewers to add review node and select book from auto-complete. Who does that way? I'm not satisfied with it.

**How I want it:**

I've a page for every book `/book-details/title-of-the-book`, where I want to provide a link/button which says `Add Review` and then it should show them the fields of Review content-type and reviewer fills it and submits. His review is submitted. and the same page shows list of all reviews for that book.

How to achieve this in drupal-7?

Answer (score 0):

Add review content type form while viewing book content type is viewed by using hook_nodeapi().

1. Create one field on review content type(node reference of book node).
2. Add that node_form in book content type view with $form_state of the book node id.
3. Create a view for review list with a filter of book content type and use this block under book content type view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an entity reference field called **Book** (field_book) on the content type **Review**
2. Download and enable [Advanced Form Edit](https://drupal.org/project/afb)
3. Create a block for your Add review form at **admin/settings/advanced-form-blocks** (type of the block: **add**, content type: **Review**
4. Now add this block to your region at admin/structure/block. Set it to appear under the content region and make. In the visibility settings set it to only be visible on the book content type
5. [Create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/1074362) enable it and paste in the following code in the mymodule.module file:

-

```
  function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'review_node_form') {
      if (arg(0) == 'node') {
        $nid = arg(1);
        $form['field_bookie'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'][$nid] = $nid;
        $form['ajax-submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'MYMODULE_create_callback';
      }
    }
}

function MYMODULE_create_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form;
}
```

Finally create a block view with a filter on content type review and add a contextual filter for Content: Book (Select "Provide default value" and "node ID from URL")